# Find the index value of a character stored in arraylist

Tags: java, indexof

I have a string `arraylist`. Need to get the index values of all elements if its value equals a specific character.

For eg need to get the index value of element if its value = "."

with `indexOf()` & `lastIndexOf()` i am able to find only the index value of 1st and last occurrence respectively.

```
ArrayList<String> als_data = new ArrayList<String>();

als_data[0] = "a"
als_data[1] = "b"
als_data[2] = "a"
als_data[3] = "c"
als_data[4] = "d"
als_data[5] = "a"
```

now i need to find the indices of `"a"`

my output should be like

```
0
2
5
```

please help me out in doing this.

Comment: why don't you take a look at [`String`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)'s docs? Also tag it appropriately if it's homework. Now that you edited your question, take a look at [loops](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

Comment: post some code so that we can investigate further.Use String.indexOf() .. quite helpful.

Comment: post some code so that we can investigate further

Comment: Are you trying to get a list of the indices of all matching characters within each string?

Comment: yes i need to get a list of the indices of all matching characters

Comment: @athresh - had misunderstood your question, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 9):

```
String string = "a.b.cc.dddd.ef";

int index = 0;
while((index = string.indexOf('.', index)) != -1) {
    index = string.indexOf('.', index);
    System.out.println(index);
    index++;
}
```

prints

```
1
3
6
11
```

If you want to do the same over a list,

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

list.add("aa.bb.cc.dd");
list.add("aa.bb");
list.add("aa.bbcc.dd");

for (String str : list) {
    printIndexes(str, '.');
    System.out.println();
}

private void printIndexes(String string, char ch) {
    int index = 0;
    while((index = string.indexOf(ch, index)) != -1) {
        index = string.indexOf(ch, index);
        System.out.println(index);
        index++;
    }
}
```

will print

```
2
5
8

2

2
7
```

**EDIT**: Update after the author clarified his question

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

list.add("abcd");
list.add("pqrs");
list.add("abcd");
list.add("xyz");
list.add("lmn");

List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if("abcd".equals(list.get(i))) {
        indices.add(i);
    }
}

System.out.println(indices);
```

Comment: saw your website looks awesome.what do u do in UK?between can u suggest me a good programming examples book which has nice examples on collections especially HashMaps.

Comment: @Deepak - Thanks mate! Why HashMap in special?

Comment: i want to explore datastructures in java like work on complex programming problems.do you have any such interesting examples on programming with code.between can u suggest me a good programming examples book which has nice examples on collections especially HashMaps

Answer (score 4):

**It's simple and stringh forword .**

int index=list.indexOf(vale);

Now returns found index value ;

Answer (score 1):

well... you can easily do this linearly with a loop:

```
private int[] getIndexe(String searchFor,List<String> sourceArray) {
List<Integer> intArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int index = 0;
for(String val:sourceArray) {
   if(val.equals(searchFor)) {
       intArray.add(index);
   }
   index++;
}
return intArray.toArray(new int[intArray.size()]);
}
```

///
I haven't tried compiling or running the above, but it should get you close.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.indexOf( mychar, fromIndex)`.

Iterate starting with fromIndex 0, then use the previous result as your fromIndex until you get a -1.